# Invalid message for p:autocomplete and readonly="true" don't work

Tags: css, primefaces

I'm trying to change styling of empty/invalid input fields on form. I'm using Primefaces, so I wanted to swtich its messages for required fields and I've done it on this way:

```
<p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{myClass.firstName}" required="true" styleClass="#{not component.valid ? 'ui-input-invalid' : ''}"/>
```

If component is empty (invalid) I add css to this input field so its border become red without any text. But, among many input fields I have, I have some fields that are p:autocomplete or fields that are read-only by default. I know fields like that aren't supposed to be marked as invalid, but I need to mark them as invalid also. Browsing Internet didn't bring any successful solution, do you have any?

```
<p:autoComplete id="city" forceSelection="true" minQueryLength="2" queryDelay="400" value="#{myClass.city}" required="true" completeMethod="#{myClass.fetchCities}" effect="fade" global="false" var="city" itemLabel="#{city.name}" itemValue="#{city}" converter="cityConverter"  styleClass="#{not component.valid ? 'ui-input-invalid' : ''}"/>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you add `required="true"` to your `p:autoComplete` it should also take your style, but why do you add your own error classes? Can't you override PrimeFaces one?

Comment: as you can see, i've added required attribute on p:autocomplete. But if I try to submit empty form, there is just label that get red, but not html input field that has been generated from p:autocomplete, and thats the reason why I didn't override PF css because it is applied only on autocomplete label, not input field. Can you suggest me some better solution?

Comment: it's like that by default, if you don't add requiredMessage attribute, than you will just get your label slightly red but that isn't enough for my case

Comment: I got my `p:autoComplete` red with `required = true` when I leave it empty. Also `requiredMessage` has nothing to do with red style. It just either prints out your message if you provide it, or if you don't do it, it will use default one - in either case there is a message if you have `p:message for="city"`. You are saying that label got error style (I assume from PriemFaces or your own error class?) but not component which causes it then this is not normal behavior.